# Concurrent requests will fail inspite of LOCKING the table

Tags: php, mysql

I programmed a "Who is only" widget for our backend. It is working, but sometimes the system will throw an *SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '42' for key 'user_id'* MySQL error. I really don't understand why this is happening, because the code runs on a locked table...

Let's start with the table structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `locktest`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `locktest`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locktest` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_access` datetime NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Test table for locking test' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


--
-- Indexes for table `locktest`
--
ALTER TABLE `locktest`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
$dbh = new \PDO(...);
$dbh->beginTransaction();

$dbh->exec('LOCK TABLES locktest WRITE');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql_update);
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':last_access', $last_access);
$stmt->bindValue(':path', $path);

$stmt->execute();

$rows_affected = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($rows_affected == 0) {
    // New data set
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql_insert);
    $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':last_access', $last_access);
    $stmt->bindValue(':path', $path);

    $stmt->execute();
}

$dbh->commit();
$dbh->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

In this example I am using PDO. But I tried the same with mysqli and Zend_Db (using PDO and mysqli)... it doesn't matter: Concurrent requests will fail and I don't understand why.

I noticed that if I remove the varchar column or replace it with another int column, that I don't see failing requests.

Also, when I add a `sleep(1)` call before the code, it is also working. Looks like a timing problem? Not? I really thought using LOCKS should prevent errors like that...

I also tried the example without TRANSACTIONS just to make sure LOCK doesn't interfere with TRANSACTIONS... no change.

Am I doing something wrong?

Tested against PHP 5.5.13, 5.3.28.
Tested against MySQL 5.1.73 and 5.6.17.

Yes, I am using MyISAM.

I created a small complete test application: https://www.dropbox.com/s/77t9jy596vodmax/locktest.zip

Comment: Not sure why it's happening, but why don't you use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to do it all in one query?

Comment: We were using *ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE* before but we have rewritten our queries to support statement-based replication.

Comment: is a user able to login from 2 different browsers or machines? This would give different ids but same user_id and as a result create a Mysql error. Why have unique for user_id in the 1st place?

Comment: @NikosM.: Think you have misread the code: The *id* field is never the problem.

Well, it would be possible that a user uses multiple browsers/machines. Because the Who-is-online widget is only interested in the last location the user was seen, we only need one data set per user and therefore we set a unique index on user_id.

But we are seeing the error in a single tab from a single user on a single system when one user seems to change location too fast... but that's why we are using LOCKING we thought...

Comment: ok i see, still if this is case (and this happens even with a user logged from a single machine), is it possible there is a timing issue in the other code. i presume the code checks periodically, is it possible to count the user twice?

Comment: 1) The code is wrapped into a class - not duplicated. 2) The code will only be called once per request - we checked that.        BUT: Even if we would call the code multiple times in a loop on the same request, thanks to the LOCKING this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem on my own:

First, there's nothing wrong with my code. It looks like LOCKING doesn't work, but it does.

The problem is, that the logic (INSERT when UPDATE doesn't affect any row) doesn't expect an intelligent MySQL server:

MySQL seems to detect that sometimes an update is not necessary and therefore reports *$affected_rows = 0* back to the application.

**When does that happen?**

Imagine the backend user requests */$module/$action* (request 1). In this example, *$module = article* and *$action = add*. So the user sees a web form for adding a new data set. If the user immediately submits the empty form (*/article/check*, request 2), the controller will detect that and redirect the user back to */article/add* (request 3) telling him/her about the required fields.

When this happens within the same time, there's nothing to update for request 2 and request 3 because request 1 already set *$user_id = $user_id*, *$last_access = time()* and *$path = $module*.

As said, this doesn't happen very often but it could if two calls to the same module will happen within the same *time()*.

**Two ways to solve the problem:**

- Make sure that each UPDATE statement is unique (use *microtime()*, also log the *action*...) so that the UPDATE statement will always affect one row if there's already a data set from the user... so that the logic will work again.
- When the UPDATE statement doesn't affect any row run a SELECT statement before the INSERT to make sure that there is no data set... (you could also always run a DELETE statement before the INSERT but to limit WRITE load I recommend a SELECT statement which is very cheap... in my case it is only another key look up).

Thanks for all the comments.